# timer in java using threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am developing an exam software in core java where I am conducting various tests for students.I am stuck at a piece of code where timer with countdown is set.
My problem is when I display minutes its working fine but when I try to display seconds with the minutes in mm:ss format its not working.

Code is:

```
// for below int ti=20,si=60;
// test is for 20 minutes
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(60000);

            for (int i = 0; i <= 60; i++) {
                etime.setText("Remaining Time:-" + ti + ":" + si);
                System.out.println("Remaining Time:-" + ti + ":" + si);
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
                si--;
            }
            ti--;
            if (ti == 0) {
                close();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Exam.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Not working in what way?

Comment: minutes are going down but seconds just showing 60 all the time

Comment: set si=60 each munites

Comment: You are sleeping for 1 minute, and then counting down another minute in your loop?

Comment: you should add another loop for munites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once `si` has counted down to 0, you need to reset it to 59.

Also, the `i` variable is completely unnecessary, and there is an off-by-one error in your loop.

Comment: In all that excitement, I forgot to actually upvote - done now :)